# Python unittest mock method which called in another module work error

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

This is my probject structure, and this problem is a MCVE.

- wrx_test

  - use_mock
  - **init**.py
  - A.py
  - B.py
  - use_mock.py

A.py

```
def do_something():
    print 'a i do something'
    return 10
```

B.py

```
from wrx_test.use_mock.A import do_something
class B(object):
    def b_do_something(self):
        x = do_something()
        print x
        return x
```

use_mock.py

```
from mock import patch
from unittest import TestCase

from wrx_test.use_mock.B import B


class TestUseMock(TestCase):
    @patch('wrx_test.use_mock.A.do_something')
    def test_use_mock(self, mock_do_something):
        from wrx_test.use_mock.A import do_something

        mock_do_something.return_value = 4
        print do_something()
        B().b_do_something()
```

In use_mock.py i set the mocked method return_value equal 4, but it doesn't work as excepted. How can i make the mocked method `A.do_something` work correctly in module B, and i wonder now the reason.

result

```
a i do something
10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way mock works is that you designate a function in a module to be replaced by your mock when this function is used in another call. Example: patch('A.do_something) would mean that if you test a function that internally calls A.do_something(), it will be replaced inside that call. But here you're directly executing that function.
I also don't see any useful case for doing this. If you want to call the mock directly, do: mock_do_something()